# Why $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] doesn't work correctly?

Tags: php, ip

I already use xampp 3.2.1 version and `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` was fine. It returned some thing like this `172.0.0.1`. But now I have updated my Xampp to 5.6.3 version and now `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` doesn't work as well, it returns `::1`.

What's the problem? And how can get the client IP now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::1` is just the [IPv6 loopback address of the localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution) compared to the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`, so it is basically the same host, just a different protocol.

Comment: Interesting ..! +1. So is everything fine if I upload my website on a real server? I mean is `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` will return client IP?

Comment: If the loopback address is what you need, it should be fine. However if you need the *client* IP, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/213685

Comment: Ah, actually I need to store user's IP to count the number of *viewed* for each post. So how should I get user's IP?